# groovy error /usr/bin/build-classpath: could not find /file/path/ Java extension for this JVM

Tags: groovy, jar

My simple groovy command

```
groovy -cp :/home/admin/dude/app/mysql-connector-java.jar code.groovy
```

shows the following error

```
/usr/bin/build-classpath: Could not find /home/admin/dude/app Java extension for this JVM
```

How to solve this and why this happening?

Update :

> This error occurs at Groovy Version: **1.8.9**.
>
> But this problem solved with the new version of **groovy-2.4.11**.

Comment: What happens if you don't put the colon in front of the classpath?

Comment: @tim_yates sorry for my late response. Same error occurs even after that colon removed. But this problem solved with the new version of groovy-2.4.11. This error occurs at Groovy Version: 1.8.9